# SQL : How to count number of times each ID exists continuously from previous period

Tags: sql

My SQL data set is like this;

```
Date    firm_id    
======================
2010-01    1           
2010-01    2           
2010-01    3           
----------------------
2010-02    1           
2010-02    2           
----------------------
2010-03    1           
2010-03    2           
2010-03    3           
----------------------
2010-04    1           
2010-04    3
```

How can I create a variable, name firm_age, to represent age of firms existing continuously from the previous period? like this,

```
 Date      firm_id    firm_age
=================================
2010-01    1           0
2010-01    2           0
2010-01    3           0
-----------------------------------
2010-02    1           1
2010-02    2           1
-----------------------------------
2010-03    1           2
2010-03    2           2
2010-03    3           0
-----------------------------------
2010-04    1           3
2010-04    3           1
```

Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What does this mean? "age of firms existing continuously"

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, you were shown a large suggestion that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality between them varies. By ignoring that suggestion, you've made it take longer for you to get an answer, as well as wasted the time of people who might make an effort to answer only to find out it won't work for your DBMS. Please [edit] your post and add that tag.

Comment: "existing continuously" refers to "the largest set of -contiguous- months such that a given company existed at each individual month of that set.

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for the PACK operator from "Time & Relational Theory", which is not supported, at least not directly, in SQL.

You are trying to find [for each given row of the table] the smallest month such that there does not exist any intervening month between that smallest month and the month of the given row such that the company of the given row did not exist at that intervening month.  Given two months, assessing the [non-]existence of such an intervening month is relatively trivial, however, finding the smallest month that makes the condition true for all intervening months is another order (*).  I wouldn't try to do this completely in plain SQL.

(*) which set of months are you going to SELECT that "smallest month" from ?  You cannot rely on the fact that all months will be mentioned in your table as there is always the slight theoretical possibility that one particular month, no companies existed at all.  (This possibility also breaks any attack on the problem based on window functions ans row_numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You want "islands" where the values are sequential.  Then you want to enumerate them.  You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by firm_id, date - seqnum * interval '1 month'
                          order by date
                         ) as firm_age 
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firm_id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that date functions are not standard across databases.  This makes some assumptions about the data representation, but the idea for the processing should work in almost any database.